# android analytics tracking issue with sdk1.5?

Tags: android

I need to use google analytics tracking for my app and it says that it is supported with versions 1.6 and higher.

But my app runs on versions 1.5 and higher and right now it does not have an issue when I add the tracking code to my manifest.

```
  <receiver android:name="com.google.android.apps.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver" android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </receive>
```

I was wondering if this will be a problem after I release it into the android market.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided you include the tag

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
```

in your AndroidManifest.xml, it should be offered to owners of 1.5 devices. If you test the app on a 1.5 device and it works fine I would expect it to work fine from the Market.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Jim,

So I just released the app and tested it from different devices and it did not cause any problems. I was also told the same thing from a Google employee when I posted the same question on Google forums